# Android Kotlin: startActivityForResult & Insert to RecylerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, activity-lifecycle, startactivityforresult

I am attempting to use startActivityForResult to return information that can be used as data to be entered into a RecyclerView in the original Activity.

In Activity 1, I have set an onClickListener for a button. Once the button is pressed Activity 2 is launched with some options. The User fills in these options and then they are returned to the Activity 1.

Activity 1 then inserts an entry into the RecyclerView with information recieved from the button press and from the options returned from Activity 2.

The problem is that once Activity 2 finishes and returns back to Activity 1 the entry is not added to the RecyclerView as it should. How can I fix my code so that the entry is added correctly?

**OrderActivity.kt - Activity 1**

```
package com.example.pos

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.multiplerecyclerview.OrderAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_order.*

const val FILE_ID = 1

class OrderActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()
    // Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param.
    val orderAdapter = OrderAdapter(this, getItemsList())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order)

        margButton.setOnClickListener {
            val food = "Margerita"
            val price = 11.90
            Toast.makeText(this, "$food clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@OrderActivity, PizzaActivity::class.java)  /* Creating an Intent to go to Dashboard. */
            intent.putExtra("foodName", "$food")
            intent.putExtra("foodPrice", "$price")
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_ID) /* Starting Activity. */
            Log.i("Order", "startActivityResult.\n")

        }

        //Set the LayoutManager that this RecyclerView will use.
        orderRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items.
        orderRecyclerView.adapter = orderAdapter

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i("Order", "OnActivityResult.\n")
        if(requestCode == FILE_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val foodPrice = intent.getStringExtra("foodPrice")
            val foodSize = intent.getStringExtra("foodSize")
            insertItem(view = margButton, foodType = "Margherita", price = foodPrice!!.toDouble(), size = foodSize!!)
            Log.i("Order", "startActivityResult success\n")
        } else {
            Log.i("Order", "onActivityResult failed\n")
        }
    }

    fun insertItem(view: View, foodType: String, price: Double, size: String) {
        val index = 0
        Toast.makeText(this, "Margerita clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val newItem = DataModel("$foodType", "$size", "$price", viewType = OrderAdapter.NO_TOPPING)
        list.add(index, newItem)
        orderAdapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
    }

    private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<DataModel> {

        list.add(DataModel("Romana","1","12.50", "Pepperoni", "Aubergine", "Ex Mozz.", "Salami", OrderAdapter.TOPPINGS_4))
        list.add(DataModel("American","1","12.50", viewType = OrderAdapter.NO_TOPPING))

        return list
    }

}
```

**PizzaActivity.kt - Activity 2**

```
package com.example.pos

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.multiplerecyclerview.OrderAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_order.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pizza.*

class PizzaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizza)

        val ss1:String = intent.getStringExtra("foodName").toString()
        val ss2:String = intent.getStringExtra("foodPrice").toString()

        val textView1: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pizzaName)
        textView1.text = ss1
        val textView2: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pizzaPrice)
        val textView3: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pizzaSize)
        val editText1: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.topping1Entry)
        val editText2: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.topping2Entry)
        val editText3: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.topping3Entry)
        val editText4: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.topping4Entry)

        tenInchButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ten inch selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            insertSize(size = "10", textView = textView3)
            setPrice(price = 9.9, textView = textView2)
        }

        twelveInchButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Twelve inch selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            insertSize(size = "12", textView = textView3)
            setPrice(price = 11.8, textView = textView2)
        }

        additionalButton.setOnClickListener {
            var cost = .90
            if(textView3.equals("10")) {
                changePrice(price = cost, textView = textView2)
            } else {
                cost = 1.1
                changePrice(price = cost, textView = textView2)
            }
        }

        premiumButton.setOnClickListener {
            var cost = 1.3
            if(textView3.equals("10")) {
                changePrice(price = cost, textView = textView2)
            } else {
                cost = 1.5
                changePrice(price = cost, textView = textView2)
            }
        }

        completeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            emptyAdditions(editText1)
            val intent = Intent(this@PizzaActivity, OrderActivity::class.java)  /* Creating an Intent to go to Dashboard. */
            intent.putExtra("foodPrice", "$textView2")
            intent.putExtra("foodSize", "$textView3")
            if (!emptyAdditions(editText1) || !emptyAdditions(editText2) || !emptyAdditions(editText3) || !emptyAdditions(editText4)) {
                intent.putExtra("topping1", "$editText1")
                intent.putExtra("topping2", "$editText2")
                intent.putExtra("topping3", "$editText3")
                intent.putExtra("topping4", "$editText4")
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            } else {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
            }
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun emptyAdditions(editText: EditText): Boolean {
        val msg: String = editText.text.toString()
        //check if the EditText have values or not
        return msg.trim().isNotEmpty()

    }

    private fun insertSize(size: String, textView: TextView) {
        textView.text = size
    }

    private fun setPrice(price: Double, textView: TextView) {
        textView.text = price.toString()
    }

    private fun changePrice(price: Double, textView: TextView) {
        var cost = textView.text.toString()
        var total = (cost.toDouble() + price)
        textView.text = total.toString()
    }

}
```

Here is Activity 1. The Buttons are on the left and the RecyclerView is on the right. Once the Margherita Pizza is pressed you are brought to Activity 2.

[image]

Here is Activity 2. Once you have selected a Size you can press complete Pizza. Once you press complete Pizza it returns you to Activity 1 and the 12 inch Margerita is added to the RecyclerView.

[image]

Error Message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pos, PID: 30885
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.pos/.OrderActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.pos/com.example.pos.OrderActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.pos.OrderActivity.onActivityResult(OrderActivity.kt:58)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
```

Comment: Why are you starting new activity1 in activity2? You should just have `setResult(int, Intent)` before finish so your source activity1 receives said result

Comment: Hi @Pawel, I changed startActivity(intent) to setResult(1, intent) and the item is still not being added to the RecyclerView.

Comment: Why are you setting meaningless int (1) as result? Use `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)` or `setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)` in case of no valid order

Comment: Thanks, I changed to your suggestion and I am getting an error message. I have updated the question to reflect the code that has been changed and the error message being recieved.

Comment: Your activity result is referencing `intent` property while it should be using `data` argument